# Почему выводит неверное количество записей?

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Доброго времени суток.

Дело в следующем. У меня в таблице  5000 записей. Чтобы узнать их количество, пишу:

```
IBTable1.Open;
Edit1.Text:=inttostr(IBTable1.RecordCount);
```

Заместо ожидаемых 5000, в едите пишет 1, из-за чего такое может быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте следующие способы:

```
IBTable1.Last; //сперва взять последнюю запись, а затем ваш код
IBTable1.First;
Edit1.Text:=inttostr(IBTable1.RecordCount);

//другой вариант
IBTable1.FetchAll;
//он же в модификации
procedure TfrmForm1.qAfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
    if (DatSet is TIBCustomDataSet) then
        (DatSet as TIBCustomDataSet).FetchAll;
end;

//третий
while not IBTable1.eof do
//...
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Если отвечать на ваш вопрос

> из-за чего такое может быть?

То нужно понимать внутренние процессы происходящие при работе с базами данных.
Суть в том что в начале переменная  RecordCount=0 , если данные в таблице есть то курсор становиться на запись и естественно RecordCount становиться 1, при IBTable1.Last; происходит перемещение курсора по таблице до последней записи соответственно RecordCount будет равно количеству строк.FetchAll делает перебор всех записей что тоже приводит к правильному (в вашем понимании) RecordCount.

хотя если посмотреть на код, то все сводиться к

```
while not IBTable1.eof do
begin
 inc(RecordCount);
 IBTable1.next;
End;
```

А сделано это для того чтобы не потреблять много ресурсов (памяти и ЦП), то есть данные в память грузятся порционно, по мере потребности.